# Matplotlib variable frequency y-axis scale

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to alter the y-axis scale of matplotlib figures to have different spacing and different steps between yticks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

x_data = np.arange(0, 1000, 10)
y_data = np.random.rand(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,2))
plt.plot(x_data,y_data, color='black', linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(x_data,y_data, marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, s=20)
rect = patches.Rectangle((450,0), 100, 14,facecolor='blue', zorder=3)
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.set_ylim(0,20)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', linewidth='0.75', alpha=.9)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', which='minor', linewidth='0.75', alpha=0.6)

plt.show()
```

This creates a figure as such:

[image]

However, I am trying to alter the y-axis to be something like this (below) so that I can better visualize the distribution of the line graph, but can still showcase the height of the rectangle.

[image]

I am trying to have the first tick spacing (0 to 0.1) be the same spacing as the next tick distance (0.1 to 1), a larger gap between 1 to 5, and then reduced spacing for ticks past 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sure of the etiquette for answering my own question, but wanted to post this in case others were interested.

Turns out all I needed was a x<sup>1/2</sup> function as was provided in an example here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/scales/scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-scales-py

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

x_data = np.arange(0, 1000, 10)
y_data = np.random.rand(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,2))
plt.plot(x_data,y_data, color='black', linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(x_data,y_data, marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, s=20)
rect = patches.Rectangle((450,0), 100, 14,facecolor='blue', zorder=3)
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.set_ylim(0,20)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', linewidth='0.75', alpha=.9)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', which='minor', linewidth='0.75', alpha=0.6)

def forward(x):
    return x**(1/2)

def inverse(x):
    return x**2

ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))
ax.set_yticks([0,0.1,1,5,10,15,20])
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(2.5))

plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the part of the matplotlib documentation that you are looking for is [yscale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) or (if you are using the object-oriented API) [set_yscale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html).

If the default available y scales (e.g. 'log', 'symlog', 'logit') are not satisfactory for you, you can create your own scale. Here is the documentation about [that](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/devel/add_new_projection.html) and an [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/scales/custom_scale.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the other available function but none of them worked as desired. That example is definitely something I was looking for, thanks for the link!